# Power BI Slicer not syncing between two visuals when one is used in a bookmark and is hidden

Tags: slicers

I created one line graph visual that shows sales for 5 years. I then duplicated the same visual to convert it into a column chart. I created a functionality using Bookmarks and buttons where I give the user the option to see the information as a line chart or column chart by selecting a button connected to a bookmark. I also created a date slicer that contains the five years. However, when I am viewing one of the charts and I select a particular range of years, the data changes as expected but if I click on the button to see the other chart that slicer selection does not carry to the chart that was hidden. I have also activated the Synch Slicers button on the ribbon.

I would like to know what I need to do further to make sure that the slicer affects both visuals, the visible and the hidden one.

Thanks!